# How to make void(*)(...) as a struct member

Tags: c++, struct, void-pointers

for a demo code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef struct Student
{
    public: 
        Student(){}
        ~Student(){}
        static void print(int a,int b){printf("age is a\n");}
}Student;

int main(){
    void (*p)(int, int) = &Student::print;

    vector<void(*)(int,int)> tt;
    tt.push_back(p);
    tt[0](1,1);

    return 0;
}
```

when I want to make the void(*)(int,int) as a struct member, like

```
struct void_func_st{
    void(*)(int,int) f;
    int a;
};
```

the code is wrong. I don't know whether the struct could be made actually as I'm not familiar with how the void(*)(...) works. Or I just didn't get the right way to make void(*)(...) as a struct member. Can anyone give some advice?

Comment: Look at the first line on `main` for correct placement of the variable name (`f`).

Comment: Please remove the c tag (since this is clearly c++, not c).

Comment: You need to use a member pointer, not just an arbitrary function pointer. `void (Student::*p)(int, int) = &Student::print;`. And quite obviously you need to have a `Student` instance to call it, `Student s; (s.*p)(1, 1);` etc.

Answer (score 6):

It would be (as you do for local variable `p` in `main`)

```
void(*f)(int,int);
```

As note, `typedef`/`using` or some "wrapper" might help to have more regular syntax, for example:

```
using bin_func = void(int, int);

bin_func* f2;
std::add_pointer_t<void(int, int)> f3;
std::type_identity_t<void(int, int)>* f4;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::function` and forget about the confusing function pointer syntax:

```
struct void_func_st {
    std::function<void(int,int)>; f;
    int a;
};
```

Even better, introduce a nice alias for it:

```
using MyFunction = std::function<void(int,int)>;
```

Comment: There's nothing in the question that indicates that the code needs all the extra stuff, and the resulting overhead, that `std::function` does.